# Throwing a fair dice untill 6 appears

Tags: probability, combinatorics, probability-distributions

We throw fair dice until $6$ will appear. Let $X$ denote total number of throws and $Y$ - number of $5$ we received.

1. Find distribution $(X,Y)$
2. Are variables $X$ and $Y$ independent?

I have to say that I have utterly no idea how to proceed with this question, detailed explanation appreciated.

Comment: OK, to get a basic understanding of this, I recommend doing the following if you have time. Draw a 2-D grid and label the axes $X$ and $Y$. Then roll a dice until a $6$ appears, counting the number of times you get a $5$ on the way and the total number of rolls. Add $+1$ to the corresponding point $(X, Y)$ in the graph. Do this experiment any number of times, and record the number of times $N$. Then add up all the $1$s in each cell and divide the number in each cell by the total number of experiments $N$. This will approximate your distribution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$X$ follow a distribution called geometric
$$P(X= x) = \left(\frac56\right)^{x-1} \times \frac16$$
Having something other than 6 for the first $x - 1$ throw, then a 6.

Of course, $Y$ and $X$ are dependant.  If you get a 6 on the first throw ($X = 1$), the $Y = 0$, you can't have any five.

Knowing the number of throws you needed to get a 6, the number of 5 is a binomial distribution.
$$P(Y=y|X=x) = Binomial\left(x-1,\frac15\right) = \binom{x-1}{y}\left(\frac15\right)^y\left(\frac45\right)^{x-1-y}$$ if $y\leq x-1$, $0$ otherwise.

The combine distribution will be, if $y \leq x-1$
$$P(X=x, Y=y) = P(X = x) \times P(Y=y | X=x) = \left(\frac56\right)^{x-1} \frac16\binom{x-1}{y}\left(\frac15\right)^y\left(\frac45\right)^{x-1-y}$$
$$P(X=x,Y=y) = \binom{x-1}{y}\left(\frac15\right)^y\left(\frac45\right)^{x-1-y}\left(\frac56\right)^{x-1} \frac16$$
The probability is $0$ otherwise.

Comment: What about the independence of X and Y? But i need to combine those two distributions you wrote? If Yes how should i do that?

Comment: They are dependant since the number of five will depend on the number of throws.  The combine distribution will simply be the product of the two.  I'll add it in the answer.

Comment: Thus justification of independence is so simple? I did not expect that.

Comment: And what do you get if you for $P(Y=y)$?

Comment: Does it matter?

Comment: No less than the original question, It's $Geom(1/2)$.

Comment: @A.S.I'll try to get the computation right, but I didn't expect $P(Y=y)$ to be that simple.

Answer (score 0):

For the first part you need the following:
$$X \sim \text{Geometric}\left(\frac {1} {6}\right) $$ and 
$$Y|X = x \sim \text{Binomial}\left(x, \frac {1} {6}\right)$$

and the joint pmf is just the product of these pmf.